# getSheetByName google apps Script returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm stuck and can't find an answer for my problem.

Here's my current code:

```
var monthSheet = sourcesheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName(monthSheet);
```

monthSheet is String
destsheet is always **null** and I don't know why...

edit:

```
function sendAnnouncement() {



 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());


  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Announcements");
  var sourceAnn = sourcesheet.getRange('B2:B2').getValue();

  var sourceMonth = sourcesheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  sourcesheet.getRange('A1').setFormula("=VLOOKUP(A2;Settings!B1:C12;2;false)");
  var monthSheet = sourcesheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var sourceTaxStake = sourcesheet.getRange('C2').getValue();


 var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName(monthSheet);
 var destTaxStake = destsheet.getRange('H2').getValues();  

  if ('sourceTaxStake' == "all")
  {
var destrange = destsheet.getRange('D8:D8'); 
destrange.setValues(sourceAnn);     
}
  else if ('destTaxStake' == 'sourceTaxStake')
  {
var destrange = destsheet.getRange('D8:D8'); 
destrange.setValues(sourceAnn);     
}
else    
{
}
```

}
}

Comment: The code looks okay. Please provide a sample file.

Comment: And can you tell us how 'shoot' is defined plz?

Comment: I've edited the post and added whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Again, that part of code itself is okay. Have you checked what value is `monthSheet`? Probably it's different from the actual sheet name. Also check its value by `Logger.log(monthSheet)`. Check my example [source sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D3cY4zmGr2dvpYN0LqfKZDeXotH44EjOfAJW_YDak1U/) and [destination sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JxjM7KJRofTRxH5pRpY4vLuY9ojKP__DYjodSIN3rVE/). Below script is included in the source sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Announcements");
  var monthSheet = sourcesheet.getRange('A1').getValue();

  var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JxjM7KJRofTRxH5pRpY4vLuY9ojKP__DYjodSIN3rVE');
  var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName(monthSheet);
  Logger.log(destsheet.getName());  // dest_s
}
```

Of course `1JxjM7KJRofTRxH5pRpY4vLuY9ojKP__DYjodSIN3rVE` is my destination sheet. And `dest_s` is the value of `Announcements!A1` on the source sheet and, in the same time, the name of sheet on the destination sheet. Check for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
I noticed that sourceTaxStake and destTaxStake had single quotes around them so  neither condition would ever by true.  I removed the single quotes and the editor immediately darkened them as it does with defined variables.

function sendAnnouncement() 
{
 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
      var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Announcements");
      var sourceAnn = sourcesheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
      var sourceMonth = sourcesheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
      sourcesheet.getRange('A1').setFormula("=VLOOKUP(A2;Settings!B1:C12;2;false)");
      var monthSheet = sourcesheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
      var sourceTaxStake = sourcesheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
      var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName(monthSheet);
      var destTaxStake = destsheet.getRange('H2').getValues();  
      if (sourceTaxStake == "all")
      {
        var destrange = destsheet.getRange('D8:D8'); 
        destrange.setValues(sourceAnn);     
      }
      else if (destTaxStake == 'sourceTaxStake')
      {
        var destrange = destsheet.getRange('D8:D8'); 
        destrange.setValues(sourceAnn);     
      }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. There was problem with correct name of the sheet.
I've also removed single quotes from conditions. Everything is working correctly.